# Change line properties on a plot from a different function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm stuck with something which is probably easy to fix, but I couldn't find anybody having this same issue on the internet.

I'm using matplotlib to plot some datas.

```
def drawFigure(self):
    global figure
    figure = plt.figure()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)
    graph = figure.add_subplot(111)
    line = graph.plot(...,...,'-',linewidth=2)

    canvas.draw()

    plt.setp(line, linewidth=10) #Works fine

def changeLineThickness(self):
    plt.setp(line, linewidth=1) #Nothing changes
```

The function drawFigure is called first. The linewidth is set to 2 and then immediatly set to 10, so this plt.setp code works fine.

However, when I call after drawFigure the changeLineThickness function, the plt.setp does nothing and the thickness remains 10.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's your `self`? It doesn't seem to be a custom Figure, or you'd be calling methods on its axes (or other components) instead of using the `plt` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so could make this work by redrawing the canvas in the function.
I don't really understand why the line got updated after the canvas.draw() call in the first function and why I have to redraw in the second function.

```
def changeLineThickness(self):
    plt.setp(line, linewidth=1)
    canvas.draw()
```

Maybe there is a faster way to do this rather than redrawing the whole canvas.

Comment: This post blurs the line between question and answer - I'd remove the extra question.  The actual answer is that the call to `setp` *does* change the line, it's just that the visualization doesn't immediately update.  If you were to, say, plot yet another line so that the canvas updated, you would see the change.  Also, I would avoid using global variables if you can possibly help it.